# Problem using arrayrulecolor and compiling with make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, colortbl, make4ht

The following example crashes when compiling with `make4ht` The problem relies on the usage of `\arrayrulecolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Example.}
\label{tbl01}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule 
A & B & C \\
\arrayrulecolor[gray]{.7}
\midrule
D & E & F \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When compiling, the following error is met:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    11   Misplaced \noalign.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    12   Missing } inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    12   Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

And in the log file we have:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\n:midrule: ->\o:noalign:
                          {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \cur:rule \a:midrule \gobble:...
l.11 \midrule
```

Is it possible to fix or avoid this error, still using `\arrayrulecolor` to change the color of rules in tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have an older version of TeX4ht, I don't get any compilation error. I don't get colored rules either, but this is easy to fix. TeX4ht saves the current rule color, but the old configuration for Booktabs didn't use this information. I've just updated TeX4ht sources to use it, so it will work out of the box soon, if you update your TeX distribution.

You can use it right not with this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}


\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11
\def\hline:color{000}
\Configure{toprule}
   {\@thisrulewidth=\csname a:rule-mag\endcsname\@thisrulewidth
%
    \Css{tr\#TBL-\TableNo-\ifnum \HRow=0
          1- {border-top:\expandafter\x:Em \the\@thisrulewidth em
 solid \#\hline:color;}
     \else
          \HRow- {border-bottom:\expandafter\x:Em \the\@thisrulewidth em
 solid \#\hline:color;}
     \fi
   }}
\Configure{bottomrule}
   {\@thisrulewidth=\csname a:rule-mag\endcsname\@thisrulewidth
%
    \Css{tr\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-
            {border-bottom:\expandafter\x:Em \the\@thisrulewidth em
 solid  \#\hline:color}}}
\Configure{midrule}
   {\@thisrulewidth=\csname a:rule-mag\endcsname\@thisrulewidth
%
    \Css{tr\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-
            {border-bottom:\expandafter\x:Em \the\@thisrulewidth em
 solid \#\hline:color}}}
\Configure{cmidrule}
   {\@thisrulewidth=\csname a:rule-mag\endcsname\@thisrulewidth
%
    \Css{td\#TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol{border-bottom:\expandafter\x:Em \the\@thisrulewidth em
 solid \#\hline:color}}%
    \HCode{<span class="cmidrule"><!-- enable post-processing of cmidrule--></span>}}

\catcode`\:=12
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This configuration declares CSS code that is inserted for Booktabs rules. The rule color is saved in `\hline:color`. It is in the hexadecimal form suitable for CSS declarations.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: I've tried v0.3f and v0.3h. Both still give me the same error.

Comment: @LEo the verson of `make4ht` doesn't really matter for this error, the important thing is if you have updated TeX Live with most recent configuration files for TeX4ht.

Comment: I've downloaded the files from https://www.kodymirus.cz/files/tex4ht-4ht-files.zip, placed them at ```/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/``` and the error persist.

Comment: @LEo that file contained older version of 4ht files. I got fatal error with them. I've updated it with the new version, so you can try it again.

Comment: great! using the updated files it works fine! :-)

Comment: @LEo that's great to hear! I think there are still some issues to fix in your class?

Comment: @michal-h21 there are still a few, but they did not prevent a good HTML generation... I will try to isolate them and post here in stack

Comment: @LEo great! I know that there are some issues with Polyglossia. I was unfortunately overwhelmed by various bug reports in the last few weeks, so I don't remember what it was. It should be better now, as I fixed most of these requests.